# Problem with the relay switching

Tags: power-supply, relay

[image: Relay switching]

I am trying to switch on and off LED's with the help of a relay.

The relay I am using is 24VDC SPDT relay and the LED is 12VDC LED.

When I switch on the 12V supply the yellow LED should glow since the relay is in normally closed condition[please refer the schematic] and when the 24V supply is turned on the relay gets activated and becomes normally open thus allowing the flow of current to turn on the red led. Eventually, cutting of the supply to the yellow led.

When testing this circuit on a breadboard, the yellow is turning on when 12V supply is given and when I turn on the 24V supply, the relay gets activated but the red led is not glowing. When I measured the voltage near the led[supposed to be 12V], it is not getting any supply itself. I am stuck at this point and don't know if I am missing any small thing here.

The relay I am using is G5LE-1-E DC24 RELAY GEN PURPOSE SPDT 16A 24V.

Comment: it's very unusual to switch LEDs with relays. It's even more unusual to use a 24 V-driven relay to drive a 12 V LED (which, by the way, is an LED + built-in resistor). Have you taken into account that LEDs don't work in both directions?

Comment: This schematic is only a part of a circuit.I had to use 24V supply. so using a 24V relay to act as a switch between red and yellow led. By the way, those are two separate led's only the Negative of both led is connected to ground of 12V. Thank you.

Comment: Have you got the relay contacts the wrong around?  The common connection should always be at 12V with the NO and NC contacts being switched over.

Comment: I checked the contacts too. Its the same way you mentioned.

Comment: " when I turn on the 24V supply, the relay gets activated but the red led is not glowing" does the Yellow LED turn off?

Comment: Yes it turns off. The 12V supply is not coming to COM of the relay itself if i turn on the 24V.

Comment: Hard to say without more information, bad wiring, bad relay, LED backwards. Double check everything. Swap the wiring on the 4 pin connectors so the red is on when 12 volt supply is on.

Comment: Ok. Let me double check one more time and get back. Thank you.

Comment: If you don't have 12 volts on the relay COM terminal when the 24 Volt supply is on, something before this circuit must be switching off the 12 volts to this circuit.